# Do internal Azure WCF services require security

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

Really simple (possibly stupid) question for the Azure experts out there.

I am currently in the process of building an application which uses web and worker roles and in the back end connects to WCF services. So in other words my web/worker roles call the WCF backend to obtain whatever data they need, currently they use certificate based authentication.

What I would like to understand is if WCF services hosted on Azure require security even if the endpoint will never be exposed publicly? Is there any reason to implement authentication on these private WCF services or is it safe to just set `<security mode="None" />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your Worker or Web Roles are able to have private endpoints that are available to other instances within the same Hosted Service, please keep in mind that those private endpoints are NOT load-balanced. 
You can check out this article to see how you can go around this issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148149.aspx

If you want load-balanced WCF endpoints, they need to be publically accessible through Azure's load balancer and thus you may want to (but do not have to) put security on top

Microsoft has been promising private load-balanced endpoints but nothing has come out yet.

HTH

Comment: Note that with the new Network ACLs, you can effectively load balance private endpoints by making them public then restricting the permissions to them to only a specific cloud service.